# null Return of Subreport to mainreport Jasper Report v4.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

This is the variable in subreport

[image: Subreport]

This is the variable in the main report

[image: mainreport]

This is when I added it in mainreport

[image]

but I keep getting null in mainreport. what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Print the variable `SubreportReturn` in your subreport and check whether it has some value other than null

Comment: it has value in subreport